# ezPublish Translation mixup

Tags: php, ezpublish

I'm trying to create a development mirror site of an ezPublish site so I can stage changes without messing up the main site.  I copied the database and the filesystem and changed the ini files to point at the new database, but when I loaded the page I found that none of my objects were being loaded.  So I break out the debug bar, and I find that for some reason the language_mask that is being used is incorrect...the bitfield is set to 4 while the mask being used in the query to load the page is 3.

So I poke around the ini files and I see a setting called `SiteLanguageList[]` which seems to set up 'backup langauges'.  I found that If I set `SiteLanguageList[]` to:

```
SiteLanguageList[]=eng-US
SiteLanguageList[]=eng-GB
```

and my site started showing up.  Yay!

However, all is not well.  When I actually try to EDIT the page in the admin, every entry shows up blank.  What makes things doubly weird is that it shows up in the admin as long as I'm merely looking at it.  And then there's this weird discrepancy, where depending on where I'm looking in the admin, it either says that the page is eng-US or eng-GB depending on where I'm looking *on the same page*.

[Seriously, what the heck is going on here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59rLS.png).  If I click the edit button, nothing shows up.

[Same question on ez Publish community](http://share.ez.no/forums/general/ezpublish-translation-mixup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Are you sure that the database
   was imported correctly? Please check
   the database using "Setup - Upgrade
   check" utilites
2. Clear all caches
   manually (run "php
   bin/php/ezcache.php --clear-all"
   from ez root directory)
3. Check the
   ez error log
   (/var/log/error.log)
4. Check the permissions for the ez
   folders (cache, settings, etc.)

Comment: #1 nailed it.  I reimported the database myself and it worked fine.  Dunno why the first and second dumps didn't work but in any case you had the right answer, so you get the points.  Yay!